# Does android os cache application files after the application has been uninstalled

Tags: android, android-sqlite, samsung-mobile

I have an android application that has an app Database file which is copied during installation. The challenge i am facing is that on **Samsung Galaxy A30** it installs the app but the DB snapshot that's being copied during installation is an old DB, all new tables that i have created are not being copied.

Also after installation, the app picks up the user's username that he was using in the old version of the app that is saved in app preferences whenever a user logs in.

I have experienced this issue on this Samsung phone only. I have installed the same APK file on Huawei and Itel and there are no problems.

Any idea what is going on??

Comment: Not sure if this has something with your issue, but there are more types of cache. If you are using User Account and the phone is connected to same cloud the  data won't be removed after uninstall and once you reinstall the app it will read from existing cache else fetch. So you will have to change to In Memory caching. Try going to the App in settings Storage and than Remove Data & Remove Cache than uninstall and fresh install. If you get the newest database probably this might be the issue

Answer (score 1):

Some OS automatically take a backup from your app data. for example, in Android Marshmallow Google introduced the "Auto Backup" feature which is turned on by default if your targetSdkVersion is >=23.
To force prevent this add `android:allowBackup="false"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: This is perfect for restricting the app from creating backup files but Is there a way to restrict the app from auto restoring the backup files during installation

Answer (score 0):

So according to  [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup), the location of the backup copy is  ***Settings > Backup and reset > App data*** on your google drive. So to make sure the app does not restore this back up during install i just removed the google account from the device. You can go to the location in google drive and delete the back up manually that's if you have access to the account.